# 3 reset button with auto submit for each and reset all

Tags: views

I created a view page with exposed filters in a block. I have three exposed filters in a view, with apply and reset button for each one.

It shows results based on the filters. It is working fine. But I need these filters each having its own reset button and reset all button resetting all three.

Can it be done through views? Should I handle through code? If so where I need to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

This following post has a nice hook_alter function that adds a reset button to exposed filters on views. It lists both code for 6 and 7.

http://fleetthought.com/blog-post/adding-reset-button-exposed-views-filters